# How to use composite aggregation with a single bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

The following composite aggregation query

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "orderedAt": {
        "gte": 1591315200000,
        "lte": 1591438881000
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "aggregation_target": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "supplierId"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggregated_hits": {
          "top_hits": {}
        },
        "filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.doc_count > 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns something like below.

```
{
  "took" : 67,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 34,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_buckets" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "aggregation_target" : "0HQI2G2HG00100G8"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "aggregation_target" : "0HQI2G0K000100G8"
          },
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "aggregated_hits" : {...}
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "aggregation_target" : "0HQI2G18G00100G8"
          },
          "doc_count" : 11,
          "aggregated_hits" : {...}
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "aggregation_target" : "0HQI2G2HG00100G8"
          },
          "doc_count" : 16,
          "aggregated_hits" : {...}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregated results are put into buckets based on the condition set in the query.

Is there any way to put them in a single bucket and paginate thought the whole result(i.e. 31 documents in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. A doc's context doesn't include information about other docs unless you perform a `cardinality`, `scripted_metric` or `terms` aggregation. Also, once you bucket your docs based on the `supplierId`, it'd sort of defeat the purpose of aggregating in the first place...

What you wrote above is as good as it gets and you'll have to combine the `aggregated_hits` within some post processing step.